# Rename multiple files, sub directories, and insert characters at specific location on OSX

Tags: shell, osx, rename

I have files and directories starting with **"cateory-icon-"** in many sub directories. I am trying to rename them recursively to **"category-icons-"**. Please note that I added missing **"g"** to the **category** and **"s"** at the end of **icons**.

I did look at tons of other questions dealing with renaming multiple files and directories but could not make any of them work for me!

A little bit explanation about the answer would be greatly appreciated.

EDITED: Here is an example of my directory structure:

```
test/cateory-icon-archery/cateory-icon-archery.png
                          cateory-icon-archery@2x.png

test/cateory-icon-automotive/cateory-icon-automotive.png
                             cateory-icon-automotive@2x.png
```

Comment: Does OSX have the command `rename`?

Comment: No, it does not as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Since you need to do this recursively, `find` is the best tool to use. To alter the name, you can use `sh` in the `-exec` call. Here is an example:

```
find /some/path -name 'cateory-icon' -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%/*}/category-icon-${1#cateory-icon-*}"' -- {} \;
```

The `${1#cateory-icon-*}` expansion gets the filename after `cateory-icon`.

Comment: Wouldn't the `category-icon-` prefix you added come before the file path this way? I believe this would end up trying to execute things like `mv ./rel/path/to/cateory-icon-blah category-icon-./rel/path/to/`

Comment: @JosephR. - no the filename would have been correct but that path would have been missing. I updated the answer.

Comment: Did not work, no errors either. I updated question with my directory structure. I didn't forget to replace '/some/path' with 'test' before trying :)

Answer (score 3):

In zsh, put the following in your `.zshrc` (or run these at the command line for a one-time thing):

```
autoload zmv
alias zcp='zmv -C'
alias zln='zmv -L'
```

The [`zmv` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) combined with zsh's [wildcards and globbing features](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) allows easy file renaming and copying. Here are several ways to do what you want:

```
zmv '(**/)cateory-icon-(*)' '${1}category-icons-$2'
zmv -w '**/cateory-icon-*' '${1}category-icons-$2'
zmv '**/cateory-icon-(*)' '$f:h/category-icons-$1'
```

Explanation for some zsh features:

- `**/` matches files in subdirectories recursively.
- Parentheses in the source expression designate groups. `$NUM` or `${NUM}` in the replacement expression is replaced by the part of the original name contain in the NUMth group.
- Parentheses around `**` are a bit quirky: you can only put them around `**/`, no more, no less.
- The `-w` option to `zmv` automatically puts each wildcard in a group (for `**`, it's the `**/` part that's in a group, with the trailing `/`).
- `$f` in the replacement means the whole source file name.
- `$VAR:h` means the directory part of `$VAR`. This is usually `$VAR` up to the last `/`, but all edge cases (`foo`, `foo/`, `/`, …) are treated correctly. The base name is available as `$VAR:t`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl for maximum portability:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy qw(move);

my $new_name;
finddepth( sub { 
                 if(/cateory-icon/){
                     ($new_name = $File::Find::name) =~ s{.*/\Kcateory-icon}{category-icons};
                     move $File::Find::name => $new_name;
                 }
           },
          '.')
```

**Explanation**

- This makes use of 2 Perl core modules: `File::Find` for recursive traversal of directory trees and `File::Copy` for recursive copying/moving of directories.
- The `finddepth` function (from `File::Find`) traverses the list of directories supplied as its second argument (`.` in this case is the current directory; modify as needed).
- The first argument to `finddepth` is a subroutine reference that is executed for every file `finddepth` encounters as it walks the tree.
- We start this subroutine off by an `if` condition: if the file name it matched has the pattern `cateory-icon` in it, then we form the new name by making the required corrections and we make use of the `move` function (from `File::Copy`) to modify the current name to the new name.

**Disclaimer**

This code is untested. Try it on a dummy directory tree first!

Comment: typo in `finddetph` - should be `finddepth`?